# Handling Assertion failure in automated testing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I am running a automated testing of a application written in VC++ and I run the debug version of the application from the command line but during the testing if assertion is triggered visual studio displays a window with options abort, retry and ignore.The automated testing can not proceed further as it requires user input to continue. Is there a way to overcome this problem. I want to consider the test case as a failure if assertion occurs and continue with the other tests.

Answer (score 0):

`ASSERT` is likely implemented as a macro.   In your testing framework, somewhere before the code-under-test, `#define ASSERT(c)  TestFrameworkCatchAssert(c, ##c)`.   Then define the TestFrameworkCatchAssert function to test the assertion, and record the result for use in a 
"Should-Not-Assert" clause in the test case code.